# Is it possible to get the number of elements of, or collate the values of, an enum class of base char?

Tags: c++, enums, char

If I have;

```
enum class AcceptableFooChars : char
{
  curlybracketopenchar  = '{',
  curlybracketclosechar = '}',
  commachar             = ',',
  fullstopchar          = '.',
  dollarsignchar        = '$'
}
```

then is there a neater way of getting;

```
static std::string acceptableFooCharacters() noexcept
{
  constexpr std::size_t enumElementCount {5};
  static const char acceptableChars[ enumElementCount ] {
    static_cast<char>(AcceptableFooChars::curlybracketopenchar ),
    static_cast<char>(AcceptableFooChars::curlybracketclosechar),
    static_cast<char>(AcceptableFooChars::commachar            ),
    static_cast<char>(AcceptableFooChars::fullstopchar         ),
    static_cast<char>(AcceptableFooChars::dollarsignchar       )
  };
  return {acceptableChars};
}
```

by accessing ALL the elements of the enum OR simply counting the values available in the enum in a more automated, and so maintainable, way?

Comment: Some of those things are possible using template trickery. See for example this library: https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum

Comment: If performance isn't too great of a concern you can replace you're enum with a `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, char>>`.  Building `acceptableChars` from that would be trivial.

Comment: Perhaps your whole approach is not the best. Why not just have it initally into a string `"{},.$"` and then access through an `enum Example { A = 0, B = 1, ..., }` where the enum values index into the string.

Comment: As a rule, having to have two matching data structures is a maintainability issue. I know this is a trivial case, but people could add an extra character to the string and nothing forces them to update the enumeration describing that string. Here, one data structure, an enum of chars, tells thew whole story... This one case for the help-file generation seems clunky.

Comment: If you need the number of elements in an enum class, you probably don't want to use an enum class.

Comment: @MFrix True enough.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Well, it does use template trickery, but at the core it relies on parsing the output of `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` or similar compiler intrinsics (which is why it [doesn't work](https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum/issues/4) for e.g. GCC < 9). Please don't use this in production code (at least not without **very carefully** reviewing whether this could lead to unfun breakages at the worst of times).

Comment: It would be nice if an enumeration type had a *.values() returning an initializer_list of all its values, wouldn't it?